# Closing "Python Requests" connection from another thread

Tags: python, python-requests

To close the application as soon as possible, can I interrupt requests.post call from another thread and have it terminate connection immediately ?

I played with adapters, but no luck so far:

```
for ad in self.client.session.adapters.values():
    ad.close()
```

Answer (score 5):

The right way to do this is to use message passing into the other thread. We can do a poor-mans version of this by using a shared global variable. As an example, you can try running this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# A test script to verify that you can abort streaming downloads of large
# files.
import threading
import time
import requests

stop_download = False

def download(url):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    data = ''
    content_gen = r.iter_content()

    while (stop_download == False):
        try:
            data = r.iter_content(1024)
        except StopIteration:
            break

    if (stop_download == True):
        print 'Killed from other thread!'
        r.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = threading.Thread(target=download, 
                         args=('http://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ISO-IMAGES-amd64/9.1/FreeBSD-9.1-RELEASE-amd64-dvd1.iso',)
                        ).start()
    time.sleep(5)
    stop_download = True
    time.sleep(5) # Just to make sure you believe that the message actually stopped the other thread.
```

When doing this in production, especially if you don't have the protection of the GIL, you will want to use more caution around the message-passing state to avoid awkward multithreading bugs. I'm leaving that up to the implementor.

Comment: Further you can use a very small content size to get a finer control over when it is cancelled. And your `content_gen = r.iter_content()` line is unnecessary ;)

Comment: `iter_content()` returns an iterator (or generator), so you should really do something like `content_gen = r.iter_content(1024)` followed by multiple `next(content_gen)`.

Comment: @Lukasa , can you tell me that when line `r = requests.get(url, stream=True)` got executed, will the response data all get downloaded somewhere in ram ? because I'm not sure when `data = r.iter_content(1024)`, where does the 1024 bytes data come from. I'm wondering that if that's the case, kill the request later is of no use, since the data has been downloaded already ( request/respond are over ).

Comment: No.

What `stream=True` means is that requests stops pulling data from the operating system once it has all the headers. The rest of the data sits in the OS socket buffer, which will eventually be slowed and stopped by TCP if you don't read from it. Until you iterate over some data in iter_content, you do not have the rest of the data in memory.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way, here is how to interrupt connection

```
def close():
    time.sleep(5)
    r.raw._fp.close()

t = threading.Thread(target=close).start()
print "getting"
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get("http://download.thinkbroadband.com/1GB.zip", stream = True)
for line in r.iter_content(1024):
    log.debug("got it: %s", len(line))
print "done"
```

However it is a hack and I don't like it, private members can change in the future,  I am returning to urllib2

Comment: These days there's also [`Response.close`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.close), which seems to do much the same thing.

Comment: This method is useful when your thread is blocked on reading from the stream, and you want to cancel the read. It seems that there's a few seconds' timeout after calling close before the reader aborts.

Answer (score 0):

So if you do the following from the interactive shell, you'll see that closing the adapters doesn't appear to do what you're looking for.

```
import requests
s = requests.session()
s.close()
s.get('http://httpbin.org/get')
<Response [200]>
for _, adapter in s.adapters.items():
    adapter.close()

s.get('http://httpbin.org/get')
<Response [200]>
s.get('https://httpbin.org/get')
<Response [200]>
```

This looks like it may be a bug in requests, but in general, closing the adapter should prevent you from making further requests but I'm not entirely sure it will interrupt currently running requests.

Looking at HTTPAdapter (which powers both the standard `'http://'` and `'https://'` adapters), calling close on it will call `clear` on the underlying urrllib3 PoolManager. From urllib3's documentation of that method you see that:

```
This will not affect in-flight connections, but they will not be
re-used after completion.
```

So in essence, you see that you cannot affect a connection that has not yet completed.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately requests is not designed this way, I guess small http requests were the main purpose. I am using it for a desktop application and client have to let being interrupted.

Comment: You may be able to dig deep into urllib3 and close the socket forcefully but urllib3 sits atop httplib and I don't know if that's even possible there. If you want that fine grained control, you could construct the entire request (and parse the response) yourself just using raw sockets. When the user wants to cancel something, you just close the socket. That's a lot of work though.